# how to speed up Ferric Chloride and copper reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism

im doing pcb etching process (for those who don't know pcb is that thing with electronics on it lmao) using Ferric Chloride and it's taking forever

is there any chemicals i can find that will speed up this process (could it also be found at home, salt or acid for instance)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Chemicals are probably not the good way to go. What is the temperature of the solution? Increasing the temperature speeds up the reaction. Btw: take the proper safety precautions when etching pcb's!